# How do you end a conversation in Bot Framework with DirectLine 3.0?

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

The only documentation I can find is regarding the activity endConversation (this is using DirectLine 3.0).

What do I do once I send the activity that is of type endConversation?

Closing the window with the chat does not properly end the conversation, I need to do this programmatically.

My code to end a conversation is currently just sending the event to the framework:

```
botConnection.postActivity({
    type: endConversation,
    from: { id: 'Bot' },
    name: 'endActivity',
    value: "The user has closed the session. You can now close this conversation.",
}).subscribe(function (id) { console.log('Command sent'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-end-conversation) states, after you send the post request to https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/YOUR_CONVERSATION/activities

with the body that you mentioned in your question, neither the user nor the bot can send any additional messages. You should get a 200 response and an activity ID after you complete the request and that is how you know that the request was successful.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2002) on having an activity type associated with the end of a conversation in DirectLine but I don't think is in production yet. I will update this answer when I get more information.

Regards,
Francisco